# Bosun how to add series with different tags?

Tags: bosun

I'm trying to add 4 series using bosun expressions. They are from 1,2,3,4 weeks ago. I shifted them using `shift()` to have current time. But I can't add them since they have the `shift=1w` etc tags. How can I add these series together? 
Thank you

edit: here's the query for 2 weeks

```
$period = d("1w")
$duration = d("30m")

$week1end = tod(1 * $period )
$week1start = tod(1 * $period + $duration )

$week2end = tod(2 * $period )
$week2start = tod(2 * $period + $duration )

$q1 = q("avg:1m-avg:os.cpu{host=myhost}", $week1start, $week1end)
$q2 = q("avg:1m-avg:os.cpu{host=myhost}", $week2start, $week2end)

$shiftedq1 = shift($q1, "1w")
$shiftedq2 = shift($q2, "2w")

$shiftedq1+ $shiftedq2
```

edit: here's what Bosun said
[image]

The problem is similar to: How do I add the series present in the output of an `over` query:

```
over("avg:1m-avg:os.cpu{host=myhost}", "30m", "1w", 2)
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include your query? You probably need to use the [Transpose function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bosun/7213/alerts-advanced-scoping/24079/understanding-the-transpose-function-t#t=201611041859414585915) or [rename](https://bosun.org/expressions.html#renameseriesset-string-seriesset), but it would help to see what other tags are included in the alert

Comment: @GregBray updated

Comment: And your goal is point wise addition for the series? or do you just want to graph them together? Changing the last line to merge($shiftedq1,$shiftedq2) will show them on the same graph, but I'm not sure about point wise addition.

Comment: point wise addition.
Rename doesn't work coz it can only rename tag keys, not values.
Transpose expects a numberSet but I have a seriesSet

Comment: This can't be done right now, but I'll make a function for it.

Comment: https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/pull/1954

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new function called addtags that is pending documentation (see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/master/docs/expressions.md for draft) which seems to work when combined with rename. Changing the last line to:

```
$shiftedq1+addtags(rename($shiftedq2,"shift=shiftq2"),"shift=1w")
```

should generate a single result group like `{ host=hostname, shift=1w, shiftq2=2w }`. If you add additional queries for q3 and q4 you probably need to rename the shift tag for those to unique values like shiftq3 and shiftq4.

If you were using a numbersets instead of seriessets, then the Transpose function would let you "Drop" the unwanted tags. This is useful when generating alerts, since crit and warn need a single number value not a series set:

```
$average_per_q = avg(merge($shiftedq1,$shiftedq2))
$sum_over_all = sum(t($average_per_q,"host"))
Result: { host=hostname } 7.008055555555557
```

Side note you probably want to use a counter for os.cpu instead of a gauge. Example: `$q1 = q("avg:1m-avg:rate{counter,,1}:os.cpu{`. Without that rate section you are using the raw counter values instead of the gauge value.

Comment: clever :-), but also just going to make a function that will delete a tagkey from a set as long as no duplicates would result in the set.

Comment: yeah... would prefer a removetags or replacetags function

Comment: @KyleBrandt @GregBray Do you see a way to add the series resulting from the `over` expression as well?